# Getting An internal error occurred during: "Launching JCuc". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, nullpointerexception, cucumber

In Eclipse while checking out Cucumber I tried to run a Junit class with following entries:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class JCuc {

}
```

Also the accompanying Java mainclass has the following entries

```
public class LoginStep {
@Given("^the url is present$")
public void the_url() throws Throwable {
    
}

@Given("^the website is loaded$")
public void the_website_is_loaded() throws Throwable {
    
}

@When("^Enter valid user name$")
public void enter_valid_user_name() throws Throwable {
    
}

@When("^Enter valid password$")
public void enter_valid_password() throws Throwable {
    
}

@Then("^I validate signin$")
public void i_validate_signin() throws Throwable {
    
}
}
```

When running with Junit 4 I'm getting the following error
[Error screenprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJOcf.png)

The above is working fine on Eclipse Neon
but I'm getting error in Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15)

This is the log entry:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2020-04-27 20:45:51.730
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching JCuc".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.localURL(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:715)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.entryString(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.addEntry(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.localizeClasspath(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getClasspathAndModulepath(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:631)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getVMRunnerConfiguration(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:860)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1017)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$2.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: As said in the comments above, there is no problem with your code. Check .log file in your workspace for detailed error. Mostly it is because of misconfigured plugin or bug in eclipse itself.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion i have added the log entry below, could you guys check and tell me what it is?